# Determining an end node from file parsed with XmlParser

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing

I have a method which needs to search an xml file which was parsed using XmlParser for an element by name and return it only if that element is an end node. For example:

```
    class xmlTest extends GroovyTestCase {
    def void test(){
        def xmlBody = """
        <rootElement>
            <elementWithOneChild>
                <endElement>Here is the end</endElement>
            </elementWithOneChild>
            <elementWithManyChildren>
                <one>1</one>
                <two>1</two>
                <three>1</three>
            </elementWithManyChildren>
        </rootElement>"""

    def parsedBody = new XmlParser().parseText(xmlBody)

    def search1 = parsedBody.depthFirst().grep({it.name() == "elementWithOneChild"})
    println search1[0].children().size()

    def search2 = parsedBody.depthFirst().grep({it.name() == "endElement"})
    println search2[0].children().size()

    def search3 = parsedBody.depthFirst().grep({it.name() == "elementWithManyChildren"})
    println search3[0].children().size()
    }   
}
```

My attempt to use Node.children().size() works except for the 1 to 1 case where an element contains one child element. In this case, search1.children().size() and search2.children().size() both return 1. Although, the size for elementWithManyChildren is 3. I am looking for some way to be able to tell an end node apart from an element with one child.

One way I have found to work is:

```
try{
    search1[0].children().iterator().next().name()
}catch(e){
   //If the next node does not have a name, it is an end node
}
```

But that solution just seems like a poor one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

might waste a couple of cycles but this should allow you to find terminal nodes

```
assert search1[0].'**'.size() == 2
assert search2[0].'**'.size() == 1
assert search3[0].'**'.size() == 4
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work and is not depth specific. Can you explain a little on what the '**' is doing?